# Rails "nested" join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, syntax

In my database, I have the following tables and relationships:

> **Inspections** `--has_many--<` **Samples** `--has_many--<` **Results**

A sample is considered 'analyzed' if it has one or more results associated to it.  An inspection is considered 'complete' if all its samples are analyzed.  I need to find all 'incomplete' inspections; that is, all inspections that have at least one sample that has not been analyzed.

My query to do this in the mysql database is

```
SELECT DISTINCT inspections.*
    FROM inspections
    JOIN samples s ON inspections.id = s.inspection_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN results r ON r.`sample_id` = s.`id`
    WHERE r.id IS NULL
```

I'm trying to turn this in to a nice ActiveRecord `find` call (aside from `find_by_sql`), but I'm not sure how to get that left join of the "nested" association (terminology?) into the syntax.

Can anyone help me out?  BTW, this is for a Rails 2.3 app.

---

For now I have

```
Inspection.all(:select => "distinct inspections.*",
  :joins => "join samples on samples.inspection_id = inspections.id " +
    "left join results on results.sample_id = samples.id",
  :conditions => "results.id is null")
```

It works, but still looks unrefined and too close to the entire sql statement.  Is there something a little cleaner than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:include` in the find statement:

```
Inspection.find(:all, :include => {:samples => :results})
```

**Edit:**

I missed the combination of `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` before. My apologies.

While it doesn't generate the same query, you could add an additional where check to filter out the inspections that don't have any samples.

```
Inspection.find(:all,
    :select => "DISTINCT inspections.*",
    :include => {:samples => :results},
    :conditions => "results.id IS NULL AND samples.id IS NOT NULL")
```

Note, however, that is approach won't perform as well as doing it with `JOIN`s.

Comment: Not quite.  If I include `:conditions => "results.id is null"` to match the SQL query, it almost works, but it's including inspections that have no samples.  I need to exclude those.